# Trouble hosting Django website in Ubuntu (Error)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I need to host a `Django` website in `Ubuntu 18 (Desktop)`. I searched the web but couldn't find a well-written tutorial which demonstrates how to do this step by step. After doing some research I came across following procedure but I believe its incomplete.

**Library installed**

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
pip3 install Django
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

The project named `mysite` with an app `polls` and virtual environment `mysite_env` is located in `/var/www` with following directory structure

[image]

Configured `wsgi.py` at follows

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Added following lines in `apache2.conf` located in `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
#ServerName mysite.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/mysite/mysite_env
#WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

If everything setups perfectly then on opening `localhost` in the browser will let `Apache` server to open `Django` app but on the other hand, by doing it `Django` app doesn't loads.

I am missing lots of things I know, I need to host it and access it on the web. Can anybody tell me what steps I am missing, Any suggestions would be of great help.

**References**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/y

Comment: If you still haven't then do take a look at this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) from digital ocean that demonstrates deployment of Django app on Ubuntu via apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this simple step to step tutorial which I can recommend. It is for Ubuntu 16.04 but I believe you can simply transfer it to 18.04

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html

Comment: They are using `NGINX` instead of `Apache`